# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to create a function to remove the features that are highly correlated with each other. However, I am getting the error  `''AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'   '' ...`

I just want to call pandas to read columns number. What can I do next?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def remove_features_identical(DataFrame,data_source):
    n=len(DataFrame.columns)
    print 'dealing with %d features of %s data......... \n' % (n,data_source)
    remove_ind = []
    R = np.corrcoef(DataFrame.T)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if R[i,j]==1:
                remove_ind.append(j)    

    DataFrame.drop(remove_ind, axis=1, inplace=True)
    DataFrame.drop(remove_ind, axis=1, inplace=True)
    print ('deleting %d columns with correration factor >0.99') % ( len(remove_ind))
    return DataFrame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load data and initialize y and x from train set and test set
    df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
    df_test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    y_train=df_train['TARGET'].values
    X_train =df_train.drop(['ID','TARGET'], axis=1).values
    y_test=[]
    X_test = df_test.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values

    # delete identical feartures in raw data
    X_train = remove_features_identical(X_train,'train set')
    X_test = remove_features_identical(X_test,'test set')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the Pandas documentation, but I think

```
X_train = df_train.drop(['ID','TARGET'], axis=1).values
```

`.values` returns a `numpy` array, not a Pandas dataframe.  An array does not have a `columns` attribute.

`remove_features_identical` - if you pass this an array, make sure you are only using array, not dataframe, features.  Otherwise, make sure you pass it a dataframe.  And don't use variable names like `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

**Check what were the names of our columns**

```
unscaled_inputs.columns.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution solve such problem, try this:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns = X.columns)

X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test, columns=X.columns)
```